# Toggling tilt switch

Tags: switching

I’m looking for a simple digital version of the functionality of a pull chain switch, but controlled by a tilt switch.

I want to put it into a book on my book case.  Tilt the book and the circuit latches and conducts.  Tilt the book again and it’s off.

I want to use the old tilt a book / Scooby Doo switch to turn on my fire place.  Currently it is a boring light switch.

Any ideas?

I can’t figure out a way to have the tilt switch activation toggle a flip-flop action. Maybe I could use a latching relay?...

Comment: Tilt the book again? Or untilt the book? For tilt again you could just make the book push or pull a momentary switch each time and skip tilt switches and relays, and for untilt you just use a regular switch. Is this book fixed to the shelf?

Comment: Post links to all interfaces

Answer (score 1):

For a one-off you could use a microcontroller + relay etc. or an Arduino + relay and driver.

Either way (assuming the microcontroller has EEPROM), you can choose whether to make the state persistent or not (so if the power fails and is re-applied the output will remain in the previous state or go to some state such as 'off').

All you need the program to do is to monitor the switch state, debounce the switch and control the output. If you require persistent state you'll need to figure out how to talk to the EEPROM (or in the case of the Arduino, use the appropriate library where someone else has done the work for you).

Personally, I'd probably use a PIC12C509 with internal clock and a BJT + 12VDC relay. About 10-12 parts total including a 5V regulator, flyback diode, bypass caps etc. Run it off a 12V or 5V wall adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an actual flip-flop plus a regular lever switch to do this -- you can pretty easily wire up a DFF to have a default state (I assume you want the fire to be off in the event of power cycling) and toggle on every clock input.  The hard part then becomes controlling the AC power (relays or solid state relays work) and powering the DC circuitry (transformer to step down power + rectifier to get DC is easiest).  It would be a bit of a project, but not all that difficult really.

Comment: The book will not be on a fixed hinge. 
It will be a book in the shelf with a wire attached to it.  
If the book is tilted a certain amount then the state would If power is lost the contact needs to fail open. 
Does anyone have the time to make something like this for me?  I’m currently unable to do this due to health issues.